# Use array (with struct) as global, without including every functions in C++ language

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have large data (array with struct).

Source1.cpp: http://pastebin.com/JebNaffT (only array with struct)

Source.cpp (main): http://pastebin.com/gtxSMpdB

I tried to make global, still no hope. Why global? Because 2x include makes more data bigger (file size increases 2x). (I think! If you know I'm wrong, then say it.) When there was only one include then it was about 300KB, now 960KB (with two includes). I think that's too much. I'd like to optimize the code, but it's my first time in C++ language. I'll need help about this, I tried to google, still no luck about finding the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including cpp files is not a great idea. For one thing, the whole cpp file gets duplicated every time you include it with the sort of nasty results you've noted. And frankly it's usually worse due to naming collisions.

If you have data in the cpp file you need to share, for example:

```
int hugeFreakingArray[] = {1, 2, 3, ..., 2147483647};
```

do this in the header instead:

```
extern int hugeFreakingArray[];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I have array with structure, not only int. So how it should look?
Please take a look into Source1.cpp.
Is this correct? `extern struct objectList;` or `extern struct ObjectList;`
Do I have create file with .h (extension) that contains this `extern` and include it in Source.cpp?

Comment: `extern struct ObjectList;` result:
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
error LNK2005: "struct objectList * ObjectList" (?ObjectList@@3PAUobjectList@@A) already defined in Source.obj)
warning C4091: 'extern ' : ignored on left of 'ObjectList' when no variable is declared

Comment: That sounds like both the declaration and the forward declaration got `extern`ed. You need to declare `struct ObjectList;` in one and only one of the compiled .cpp files and `extern struct ObjectList;` in one included header.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Source.cpp: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/A8P0cnNA)
Header.h: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/wsDxJ9du)
Still got some errors: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/6eTnXcEB)
What's problem?

Comment: In the header: `extern struct ObjectList;` missed type of ObjectList and the fact that it is an array. Need `extern struct objectList ObjectList[];` You can drop the `typedef` at the front of the structure definition because you provide no alternate name. And to make your life easier, consider replacing `char* oName;` with `std::string oname;` Less memory management issues.

Comment: Thank very much for reply. Now no errors (because I had to move large array data into Source.cpp (main file) - these was about 2 errors). Can't I just move large array data to another file and include it? It's very bad to scroll when all data is in one .cpp file.

Comment: @Typhome Do not `#include` data files. Make another cpp file and put your data array in the new file. Then add the new file to your makefile or to the build list in whatever IDE you are using. If you use the IDE to create the file, this should be automatic.

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I move array data ex. `objectList ObjectList[] = { {...}, {...} };` into <new file>.cpp then I'll get "ObjectList is undefined". I have no idea how to get rid of this. I tried to include this `struct ObjectList;` into new file (cpp) and this didn't make rid of this error.

Comment: Not sure where you are at at this point and we've strayed pretty far from the original question. Time for a new question.

Comment: You said that I should put large array data to another cpp file. I did it, but then error appears about `ObjectList is undefined`. I tried to resolve this by adding `struct ObjectList;` to same cpp file where's large array data, but it didn't solve error. What wrong I did? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio (IDE).

Comment: You need at least three files. One .h defining `struct objectList` and forward-declaring `extern struct objectList ObjectList[];`. One .cpp file that `#include`s the .h file and declares  `struct objectList ObjectList[]={dataset goes here}`. Finally one or more .cpp files that  `#include` the .h file and use `ObjectList`. All of the cpp files must `#include` the .h file, all must be compiled, and all must be linked. Visual Studio should do the compiling and linking for you, but you need to ensure the `#include`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think I've got it, but I'm having now IntelliSense errors. When I want get array length by using this code: `sizeof(ObjectList) / sizeof(*ObjectList)` then it result error: `IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed`

Source1.cpp [LINK](http://pastebin.com/8WTCtbER)
Source.cpp (main) [LINK](http://pastebin.com/6RFE7cZU)
Header.h [LINK](http://pastebin.com/3JqNmuqU)

Comment: That's because while `extern struct objectList ObjectList[];` tells the compiler that "ObjectList exists. Trust me." it doesn't tell the compiler how big it is. Add to header.h `extern const size_t num_Objects;` and add `const size_t num_Objects = sizeof(ObjectList) /sizeof(*ObjectList);` after the definition of ObjectList in source1.cpp. You don't need to define `struct ObjectList;`in source1.cpp, by the way; including header.h takes care of it for you.